# Why all compilator Pascal like don’t work?

Tags: programming-languages

Why all compilator Pascal like don’t work?

Hi, in my university we study the Pascal like, but i don’t find a good compilator. Can you Hep me?
 All compilator that i found don’t work!

Comment: By "compilator", do you mean compiler?

Comment: Freepascal; could this help you? https://www.freepascal.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) then there are both free and commercial options. The [Lazarus IDE](https://www.lazarus-ide.org/) (which uses a free-pascal compiler) is pretty powerful and gives the same tools as you may be used to from the [Delphi-IDE](https://www.embarcadero.com/fr/products/delphi) which is commercial, but may be free under student license (It was a long time ago, not sure if that is still the case).

Though these IDE's are very much oriented towards the development of pascal programs with a Graphical user interface, they also allow you to create simple console programs.
Of course for the latter you can always return to the classics like [Turbo Pascal for Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/turbopascal-wdb/), which is free as well.

You can of course also have a look on the wikipedia page of [free pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Pascal) to find more IDE's.